# Error while executing process /home/asus/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, cmake

I want to import a yolov3 library. The Yolov3 library add my project but i dont build app.

My Graddle Error;

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/asus/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/asus/Masaüstü/YoloV3Tiny_Android_BlindNavigation-master/Demo7/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
FAILED: /home/asus/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android28 --gcc-toolchain=/home/asus/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/asus/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -c /home/asus/Masaüstü/YoloV3Tiny_Android_BlindNavigation-master/Demo7/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
/home/asus/Masaüstü/YoloV3Tiny_Android_BlindNavigation-master/Demo7/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'darknet/src/darknet.h' file not found
#include "darknet/src/darknet.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

My Graddle;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo7"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary340')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    //    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
}
```

I tried to clean the project and re-install it, but this did not succeed. What should I do about this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: still couldn't find a solution.